# Why Blazor randomly terminates a cookie session

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My app is split in one Blazor Server app and one web API backend running on .NET 6. The Blazor app fetches data by making API calls to the backend after having established a session. The backend handles the session (cookie-based).

After initial login my app works during 30 secondes to ~3 minutes. If I stay on the home page and refresh it, I stay logged in and it is ok, but when I go on any other page, unless those few random minutes have not passed yet, I am logged out (the app tries to redirect me to the /Account/Login method), which is materialized by the fact that the cookie is no longer sent in HTTP headers passed to the backend (which checks for a logged-in session before redirecting to the Login method).

I initially thought that this was a backend-side session timeout, but finally I think not, since refreshing the home page does not make any error show up, the backend keeps responding correctly, until I take another route, which then triggers the timeout (which has virtually occured already, but does not show up if I only query the home page).

The bottom of the code of the login method is as follow (after initial proprietary credentials/roles check) :

```cs
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

                    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(12),
                    // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
                    // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
                    // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

                    IsPersistent = true
                    // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
                    // multiple requests. Required when setting the 
                    // ExpireTimeSpan option of CookieAuthenticationOptions 
                    // set with AddCookie. Also required when setting 
                    // ExpiresUtc.

                    //IssuedUtc = <DateTimeOffset>,
                    // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

                    //RedirectUri = <string>
                    // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
                    // redirect response value.
                };
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                    authProperties);
```

And the startup code of the backend configures cookie options as follow :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
                    });
```

If I replace the ExpireUtc value by something like 10 seconds, I am logged out after 10 seconds of no activity, which is normal. But now that the value is 12 hours, I should not be disconnected after some minutes, so I think the problem comes from the Blazor app, rather than the session handling in the backend (remember that the backend denies access only because the cookie is no longer sent).

On Blazor, the configuration relative to the cookie is the following :

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
}
```

However on the browser the cookie expiration date is shown as "when the session ends" rather than 12 hours after creation.

So I really don't understand why there is a random session timeout, but I think I missed something on the Blazor side, maybe in configuration. Of course I could just implement the /Account/Login method, but I just want this cookie timeout not to happen at all.

While the app may be deployed and work using HTTPS, the same problem happens both in HTTP (when I run both servers in local) and HTTPS.

Edit : I tested the backend API using Postman and I stay logged in after periods of more than 8 minutes between two requests, thus I doubt that the timeout occurs because of the backend server, and I emphasize on Blazor instead.

Comment: Your browser will put inactive tab to sleep. I wonder if it's connected to your issue.

Comment: @maciek This should not happen since I use only one tab and the logout happens while I'm focusing it

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I think you are refering to my second code block : I already set the ExpireTimeSpan to 12 hours.

Comment: @andrea did you try setting it also in your third code block (the one for Blazor)?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Unforunately it still doesn't work. However, I should point out that the cookie problem is between the Blazor Server and the backend, not between blazor client and blazor server. I think I miss a cookie config in the HttpClient that send requests to the backend

Comment: Can you see Cookie in your browser?

Comment: @Jerry Yes, the cookie never disappears in the browser. However, this problematic cookie session is between Blazor server and the backend, not between the browser and blazor. I think that the missing configuration is in the HttpClient making the actual API calls.

Comment: @andrea Can you post code about how did you login to backend API?  Is it using navigationmanager? I'm a bit confused. SigninAsync returns cookie to cookie if it is browser request. But fetching backend API you are not using browser request. It is httpclient without any cookie by default.

Comment: @Jerry It was a simple API call (POST) to the backend. Then I thought that the HttpClient instance retained the cookie returned by this POST command to make further API calls. The line was this one : HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"{paramsConnections.DashboardUrl}/api/login", postBody)

Comment: It seems you solve this issue in another question. would you mind also post that answer in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and posted in other topic (which described my problem more specifically) :
[Why HttpClient drops cookie and change socket every 2 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75602168/why-httpclient-drops-cookie-and-change-socket-every-2-minutes/75604484#75604484)

It seems that the relevant MS documentation page is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0), in the "HttpClient and lifetime management" section.