# Why HttpClient drops cookie and change socket every 2 minutes?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app making Web API calls to a .NET6.0 backend server using HttpClient. The frontend is divided in two Razor pages, one that keeps refreshing data every minute if I stay on it (the home page), and a second page that prints data only when it get focused. The communication between the blazor app and backend has to be done under authenticated session, which is managed by a cookie. There is no problem on the backend side with the cookie, since testing the API with Postman shows me no error. But using Blazor, changing from one page to another after 2 minutes since the session establishment (login) triggers a disconnection : the backend stops responding me with data and instead tries to redirect the HttpClient to /Account/Login.

Analyzing HTTP packets with Wireshark shows me that the HttpClient itself seem to be kinda "reset" every 2 minutes (only by taking a different page), since the TCP source port is the same when I stay on the home page, but once I focus the second page (unless the 2 minutes did not pass yet), the TCP source port is different, which hints that this is a different socket connection. Because the connection is not the same, the client does not retain the cookie, and because it does not send it to the backend, the backend assumes that the client is not logged in.

The code which fetches data on the home page is as follows:

```cs
private async Task getHomeDashboard()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage fileTraitementResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{paramsConnections.DashboardUrl}/api/home/filetraitement");
        if (!fileTraitementResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) { Snackbar.Add($"Une erreur est survenue : {fileTraitementResponse.ReasonPhrase}", Severity.Error); }
        else { fileTraitement = await fileTraitementResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<FileTraitement>(); }
```

This getHomeDashboard method gets called every minute, and it keeps working if I don't leave the page before the 2 minutes "timeout".

It calls HTTP GET on several URLs under the /api/home path. They all work correctly until I go on the second page. Once I go on the second page, the home page doesn't work anymore if I go back to it. It's a different connection and the cookie is no longer sent. Even after this timeout, the source port continue to change every 2 minutes (but it shows up if I switch from home page to second page or vice versa, the refreshing of the home page does not reset the connection).

On the second page there is only one API call, but this is the same format (only the URL changes).

The httpClient variable is injected in the two pages using the @inject command, it is created in the Program.cs by the following line :
`builder.Services.AddHttpClient();`

As an example, here the she source port when I'm on the home page is 49395 :
[image: Wireshark screenshot]

In the HTTP header, the cookie is sent correctly.

Then if I go on the second page (calls /api/loto) :
[image: Wireshark screenshot 2]

The source port is different, and in the HTTP headers, the cookie is no longer sent. I think that internally in Blazor this is a different instance of HttpClient, but I don't know why.

Then if I go back on the home page, it re-uses this same new source port (for 2 minutes unless I stay on the home page), and the initial cookie does not come back. Of course I could implement the /Account/Login to restore a session, but I just want the initial session to be kept alive without any timeout.

Note that the 2 minutes timeout does not start after the login, but after the HttpClient is first used, that is when I come on the home page before the login (the page first fetches some data from the backend that does not require a login). If I stay 2 minutes on the login page, and then I login, the timeout occurs immediately (the cookies "dies" already).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by configuring the HttpClient in the Program.cs file :

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient").SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));
```

This set the "timeout" to 12 hours instead of 2 minutes by default.

Then in each Razor file using the injected HttpClient, I replaced the reference to the injected httpClient by an injected httpClientFactory (of type IHttpClientFactory), and then instancing an HttpClient each time I want to make an API call :

```
HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");
HttpResponseMessage fileTraitementResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(/* ... */)
```

This does not change the fact that every 2 minutes it's another TCP source port sending the HTTP requests, but at least the cookie is still there.

Comment: `AddHttpClient(DefaultOptions.DefaultName)` will allow you to configure the default httpclient, if you don't want to use a named one everywhere.